# Codeigniter- The upload destination folder does not appear to be writable

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, file-upload

When I am running on localhost, it is fine. After uploaded on server.one error thrown-i.e.
The upload destination folder does not appear to be writable.
This is my controller-

```
function do_upload()
    {
        $path = './uploads/';
        chmod($path,0777);
        $config['upload_path'] = $path; 
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '1000';
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768';
        $config['encrypt_name']  = TRUE;
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            $pic_path= 'uploads/'.$data['upload_data']['file_name'];
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('txt_title','Title','trim|required|xss_clean');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('category', 'Select Category', 'callback_select_validate');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('description','Description','trim|required|xss_clean');
            if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            {
                redirect('upload');
            }
            else{
            $title =mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($this->input->post('txt_title')));
            $category = $this->input->post('category');
            $description = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($this->input->post('description')));
            $this->load->model('user');
            $suc_mesg=$this->user->insertPic($pic_path,$category,$title,$description);
            $this->load->view('upload_success', $suc_mesg);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my view page-

```
 <?php 
        echo $error;
            echo form_fieldset('Upload Category Pics');

            echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload');
            echo '</br>';
            echo form_label('Title','title');
            echo '<input type="text" size="30" name="txt_title" placeholder="Enter title to pic"/>';
            echo '</br></br>';
            echo form_label('Choose Category Pics', 'category');
            $options = array(
                      'null' => '--Please Select--',
                      1  => 'Technology',
                      3    => 'Entertainment',
                      2 => 'Politics',
                      4   => 'Sports'
                    );

        echo form_dropdown('category', $options, 'category');
        echo "<br></br>";
        echo form_label('Description','description');
            $data = array(
                'name'        => 'description',
                'id'          => 'description',
                'placeholder'       => 'Enter description',
                'rows'        => '5',
                'cols'        => '40',
            );
        echo form_textarea($data);
        echo '</br></br>';
        echo form_label('Browse Pics','pics');
        echo '<input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />';
        echo "<br></br>";
        echo '<input type="submit" value="upload" />';
        echo '</form>';
        echo form_fieldset_close(); 
        ?>
```

I'm unable to find my bug,where exactly am wrong. is there anybody ready to help me plz?

Comment: Are you sure your upload folder is writable ? I see that you are trying to chmod but do you have permissions for that? Its possible that your PHP user cant chmod it .. For that you may need to change it manual.

Comment: change your upload folder permission manually !

Comment: I don't know how to check whether my upload folder is writable or not .Please tell me.

Comment: Hi DBK, how can i change upload folder permission manually,tell me

Comment: If you are using Ubuntu then the syntax is sudo chmod 777 -R /path/to/upload/folder

Comment: Thanks every body, I solved my problm.

Answer (score 0):

If the folder is for loading files by users than permisision 777 is required.

It's up to you to validate what files are loaded through upload script. Also you can use .htaccess to alow or not alow certain files to be executed from that directory.

The documentation for upload in codeigniter it's pretty simple and intuitive. Also here you can look at some ways to validate the type of files that are uploaded http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Answer (score -2):

I changed my uploads folder on web server as writable, so now it seems working.